# Get all fields of row with highest value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im learning postgresql with a table of `users`. I tried to get the oldest user with a search query that **also returns his name, id and city**  :

I starte like this:

```
db/us=# SELECT MIN(birthday) FROM users
```

But this gives me like expected only the birthday of the oldest user: `1899-10-18`

How can i also get the name,id and city ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep any ties, you can join into an inline view:

```
select u.name, u.id, u.city, u.birthday
  from users u
  join (select min(birthday) as min_birthday from users) v
    on u.birthday = v.min_birthday
```

Alternatively you could use a subquery in the WHERE clause:

```
select name, id, city
  from users
 where birthday = (select min(birthday) from users)
```

If you do not care about keeping ties you can use LIMIT:

```
select name, id, city, birthday
from users
order by birthday
limit 1
```

Comment: Thanks but i think @michaelgulak answer is faster!

Comment: @JohnSmith his answer does not make sense, you have to use a subquery or limit if you want to find the user with the earliest birthday value on the table

Comment: @JohnSmith Yep, I was completely off on that one. I apologize for the confusion. I misread your question and made other errors on top of that, and SQLFiddle was throwing odd errors and was my only avenue of testing given where I was at the time, so I (unwisely) submitted my answer anyway.